# longPressAndDrag for Android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, testing, detox

I need to simulate `longPressAndDrag` in Android as it is only supported in iOS by `detox`.

https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/api/actions/#longpressanddragduration-normalizedpositionx-normalizedpositiony-targetelement-normalizedtargetpositionx-normalizedtargetpositiony-speed-holdduration--ios-only